# Does production date affect compability or lifetime of a drive?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, storage

Yesterday we received some new drives for our in-house fileserver. We ordered 6 12TB HC520 from a supplier and they sent us four which are labeled 4 MAR 2020 and two labeled 18 AUG 2018.

They are meant to be used in a single volume, operating underneath ZFS in a 4:2 configuration (two drives failure protection).

Will the different dates have an affect on the performance or aging of the disks, are the older disks more prone to failure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually it's a good thing that you have mixed batches.

HDD manufacturers sometimes have faulty batches. Disks from a bad batch tend to fail around the same time. That's no good because your RAID redundancy works on the assumption that disks die randomly.

Some people intentionally buy different disk models or try to mix disks from different batches to avoid this issue. And you've received mixed batches without asking for them.

I wouldn't worry too much about these two. You can run a little stress test to make sure they're good, for example fill them up with zeros.

Answer (score 3):

If the drives were stored at a cold, dry place not exposed to sunlight or other radiation, their age should not make you worry.

However, some manufacturers update hard- and firmware between different batches and without notice. This can lead to unexpected behavior. E.g. Western Digital recently [implemented SMR](https://blocksandfiles.com/2020/04/14/wd-red-nas-drives-shingled-magnetic-recording/), which makes the new batches less suitable for certain use cases.

That is the reason why I prefer disks from the same batch, but as the other answer suggests, there are also reasons to mix different batches.

However, at least you want to make sure all disks run the newest firmware.

Comment: AFAIK the 2-6TB EFAX models from WD were always SMR, while older EFRX models which they replaced were CMR. It wasn't a mid-product life change.

Comment: @gronostaj You are right, WD changed the model number, but they did not communicate the according hardware changes. If one you just orders a bunch of "3TB WD red" it could very well be the case to receive different drives, since they did not change the name of the product (e.g. to "3TB WD Red v2"). I think it depends on ones perspective and yours is completely valid. Feel free to extend my answer accordingly.